# A tricky DateTime algorithm problem

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, datetime

.NET gives me the current time in both local and UTC time zones (or any other) in the DateTime struct.

Given only hour/minute variables, find when the next occurrence of this time period (eg 6:30 PM/AM) will occur, with the ability to retrieve more future times at will.

It sounds easy but indeed friends this has been breaking my noodle for a good while.

Edit:

Example:

```
~-------|now|------??-----------|future known time|------------~
~-------2pm------??2-----------9am------------~
??2 = 19
```

Comment: What do you think is tricky about this?  For example, do you think this is tricky to do this with pencil and paper?  If so, the algorithm is not tricky.  It is just a matter of translating it into code.  Or are you worried about the weird edge cases like time periods that overlap changes to daylight savings time, etc.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: And how do these questions get upvoted and that too so quickly?

Comment: A broken clock is correct twice a day...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to know how much time has to pass in order to hit the next given hour:minute.  You can use the `TimeSpan` struct for this.

```
    //this is your target time from 1 to 12 h
    var future = new TimeSpan(11, 30, 0);

    //TimeOfDay gives you the time elapsed since midnight as a TimeSpan
    var difference = future.Subtract(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);

    //check for negative TimeSpan, 
    //it means the target time occurs on the next day, just add 24 hours
    if (difference < TimeSpan.Zero)
        difference = difference.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

Now you have a `TimeSpan` that represents what you need.  You can use its properties to express it as you seem fit.  For example:

```
    difference.TotalHours; //(double) total time as a fractional hour
    difference.Hours;      //(int) just the hour component of the total time
```

As for retreiving more future times (am and pm), you can just add 12 more hours to `difference` to get the next occurence.

Comment: It needs to be able to use the same time twice a day (eg 4am and 4pm.)

Comment: @George In that case add 12 hours instead =)

Answer (score 0):

This was cooded in stackoverflow form, so it's probably there are some typos. Either way, you'll get the big picture.

```
public DateTime search(int hour, int min) {
  if (hour >= 12)
    return partialSearch(hour - 12, hour, min);

  else
    return partialSearch(hour, hour + 12, min);
}

public DateTime partialSearch(int morningHour, int afternoonHour, int min) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now;

  if (now.hour == morningHour || now.hour == afternoonHour) {
    if (now.minutes <= min) {
      return now.AddMinutes(min - now.minutes);
    }
    now = now.AddHour(1);
  }

  now = now.AddMinutes(-now.Minutes); // set the minutes to 0
  while(now.hour != morningHour || now.hour != afternoonHour) {
    now = now.AddHour(1);
  }

  return now.addMinutes(min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understood your requirements, but it seems you are looking for something like this?

```
public class TimeIterator
{
    public DateTime CurrDateTime { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetTimes(short count)
    {
        for (short i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            yield return this.CurrDateTime.AddHours(i * 12);            
    }

    public TimeIterator()
    {
        this.CurrDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

This code can be easily adjusted to work with any time interval - not just 12 hour interval